# How to change text color & font of QComboBox

Tags: text, fonts, colors, qcombobox

I'm trying to change text color of QComboBox.
I've been used stylesheet or palette.
But, they changed the color of all text item in dropbox.
I want to change the color and font of only currently selected text of combobox, not dropbox.
Please help me how to change them and show me some example code.
Thank you.

```
// It is my code:
QStringList itemList;
itemList << "item1" << "item2" << "item3" << "item4" << "item5";

ui->comboBox->addItems(itemList);
ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(2);
ui->comboBox->setItemData(2, QColor(Qt::red), Qt::TextColorRole);

// this is the ways to use stylesheet
// ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { color: blue; font-weight: bold; }");

// this is the ways to use QPalette
QPalette pal = ui->comboBox->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Text, Qt::blue);
ui->comboBox->setPalette(pal);
```

Comment: Could you please paste your code? That would be easier to help you to figure out the issue